# Store foreign key depending on the enum

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

Few days ago I switch (due to my student project) to Entity Framework and I have to develop Entity whos foreign key will depend of ENUM value , I spend last two day trying to figure it out but unfortunately I was not able to figure it out , so I hope someone here will be able to help me with it :)

Seller.cs

```
Public int Id {get;set}
public string FullName {get;set}
public string Country {get;set}
public int CentralizationId {get;set}
[ForeignKey("CentralizationId"}
public Centralization Centralization {get;set;}
```

Buyer.cs

```
Public int Id {get;set}
public string FullName {get;set}
public string Country {get;set}
public CurrencyType CurrencyType {get;set;}
public int CentralizationId {get;set}
[ForeignKey("CentralizationId"}
public Centralization Centralization {get;set;}
```

Centralization.cs

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public Author Author { get; set; }

    public Type Type { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
 
    public enum Type
    {
    Selling = 1,
    Buying = 2,
    }
```

So basically what I need is that if Type = 1  on typeId to be Seller.Id where later via getAllIncluding I will be able to get his date (somehow typeId should depend on Type)

I tried using Getters and Setters but didn`t help at all

How I think at the end should looks like for example :

```
Type = 1 (Selling)


[ForeignKey("TypeId")] 
 
 public Seller typeId {get;set;}
```

Hope someone here will be able to help me :)

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Enum for a FK/PK. EF will typically treat this as an `int` in the database.

For instance if in a database I want a "Type" table with an TypeId to enforce referential integrity but I don't necessarily want a "Type" entity, I just want an enumeration to represent that type:

```
public enum Type
{
    None = 0,
    Buying = 1,
    Selling = 2
}

public class Something
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // ...

    [Column("TypeId")]
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}
```

I would recommend a name that is more descriptive than just "Type" to avoid naming collisions with system types. I.e. "OrderType", "TransactionType" etc.

The `[ForeignKey]` attribute is used to nominate the FK fields for relationships between entities. In this case we aren't using an entity, but an enumeration so we just use `[Column]` to tell EF what the column should be named.

The above works for DB-First implementations. If you want to use Code-First where the EF definitions will be responsible for creating the schema, you will need to manually add migrations to create the "Type" table and set up the FK between it and your other table. Otherwise EF will merely leave that TypeId column as a regular column on the "Something" table.

Alternatively you can use Enums as a FK/PK which can allow you to define additional properties to go along with the relationship, and let Code First manage the table relationships as well:

```
public enum TypeIds
{
    None = 0,
    Buying = 1,
    Selling = 2
}

public class Type
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public TypeIds TypeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Something
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // ...

    [ForeignKey("Type")]
    public TypeIds TypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Type Type { get; set; }
}
```

This allows you to use the Enumeration as both a PK of an entity containing relevant details about the enumeration, and as the FK within the related entities.

Enumerations as PK/FK are useful in cases where you might have business logic dependent on those states. The important thing to consider with enumerations is that the Application rather than the database should be in control of the ID assignment, hence the use of `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` on the PK of our Type entity/table. This tells EF that the database should not use an Identity but rely on the consumer (our code) to set these IDs. We want to ensure that it is as clear as possible that our Enum is the source of truth for these keys.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for all this information they are really useful to me , I just have one question and (maybe I did not write good on my question) how could I for example get data from "Selling"  if Enum is equal 2 

Then typId should have relationship with Selling.Id ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you update your question with the complete schema? (tables/entities in question) I would avoid situations where you might have something like a field called RelatedId as an example where if an Enum is Buying then RelatedId should be treated as a FK to a Buying.Id, vs. Selling then RelatedId should be a FK to Selling.Id.  This violates referential integrity in that you cannot have a FK between either tables in that case.

Comment: sorry for late reply how you will be able to help me with this since I still did not find out how to make it . 

Have a nice day !